# MySQL workbench is not working on windows 10

Tags: mysql-workbench, windows-10

I hope that I am not spamming.
I recently upgraded my windows to windows 10 from windows 7. I re-installed MySQL Workbench. But I am not able to open it, there is no error message as well.

I also followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020024/upgrading-to-windows-10-breaks-mysql-workbench)'s suggestion, but still am not able to open MySQL workbench.

I also upgraded `mysql community server` pack to latest version. I am able to use `mysql odbc connector` to connect to remote server. But MySQL workbench is not working.

Any solution?

#### EDIT: System Error Log

```
Faulting application name: MySQLWorkbench.exe, version: 6.3.6.0, time stamp: 0x56698b0d
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d1de
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000071f08
Faulting process id: 0x85c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d13bdf2049ff98
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\MySQLWorkbench.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: b4d23999-f7f8-4a23-a770-085904b014f6
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Essential info is missing in your question. Which WB version do you use (latest?)? Did you check the log (in your user/roaming/mysql folder)? Did you check the system log? Do you see any error message that could help?

Comment: @MikeLischke , I just added error log which also includes version.

Comment: Uhm, faulting in kernelbase.dll, not very detailed output... I guess this needs a bug report, to be fixed (http://bugs.mysql.com).

Comment: Thanks, I have submitted the bug.

Comment: Reference: [link](https://bugs.mysql.com/79720)

Answer (score 0):

This exact situation happened to me. In my case, it was because I went into the program files and then did a cut and paste of the shortcut there and placed it on the desktop. I was unable to launch Workbench from the desktop after doing this. After many attempts, I thought to just open the shortcut from its original location in MySQL/MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE. Now, it works every time.

You can also right click on the shortcut in the program files and click create shortcut or click Send to and pick a location for the shortcut (this method worked fine for me when choosing the Desktop, at least). Cut and paste does not work for some reason. I hope this helps you or anyone else having the same problem. This is all assuming you have the latest versions of Visual C++ and Microsoft .NET Frameworks already installed on your computer.